# Scraping majority of text in body

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'm learning how to use lxml/BeautifulSoup and I was wondering how I can do this as convenient as possible.  The source has this structure for its body:

```
<p class = "info">
    <!-- a bunch of other tags and text in each paragraph class -->
</p>
<p class = "filler1">
</p>
<p class = "filler2">
</p>
<p class = "filler2">
</p>
<p class = "repeat">
</p>
<p class = "repeat">
</p>
<p class = "descr">
</p>
<p class = "descr">
</p>
<p class = "descr">
</p>
```

At the moment I'm simply using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('savedPage.html'))
soup.body(text=True)
```

to scrape all the text in the body.  I was wondering if there's a quick, convenient way to:
1) scrape all the text that are in the paragraph classes after "filler2", and
2) avoid escape-sequences

Regarding 2), I know I can sort of bypass this problem by iterating with

```
for i in range(1,len(soup.body(text=True))+1):
    soup.body(text=True)[i]
```

which will interpret all the escape sequences.  However, for 1), is there a way to scrape all text after the "filler2" class that still keeps the code simple?  Don't want to traverse the whole tree or be writing regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this -
Assuming that you're trying to get most of the text from the body.

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(link)
content = data.read()
# replace the script and style tags with html comments, so the bs4 just skips them
content = content.replace("<script", "<!--")
content = content.replace("</script>", "-->")
content = content.replace("<style", "<!--")
content = content.replace("</style>", "-->")
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml") # assuming you've imported lxml and bs4
comments = soup.findAll(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
Comments = [comment.extract() for comment in comments] # remove the commenys
words = []
for i in soup.stripped_strings:
    print i
# i will print most of the text of the page line by line
```

well, this approach is not the most cleanest one. But it should work fine.

Comment: Isn't there a better way to remove script and style elements?

Comment: well I found this the most easiest/effective way to remove script and style elements.